# Fill a select box using geckofx c#

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I am using the code:

```
((GeckoSelectElement) geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("OA0001_dob_month")).Value = "Jul";
```

But its not working. How to select a value in a selectbox in geckofx c# without using the jscontext?

Comment: You mean to set a value or select a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select a value by index:

```
var document = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document;
var selectElement = (GeckoSelectElement)document.GetElementById("OA0001_dob_month");
selectElement.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the text value like this selectElement.Value = "parent/child";