# Select an item from a drop down in GeckoFx

Tags: c#, geckofx

Html code/example of dropdown:

```
<select class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" style="max-width: 235px" ng-model="blogerj" ng-options="blogerj.long_name for blogerj in blogerj track by blogerj.id">
  <option class="" value="">[Choose...]</option>
  <option label="label 1" value="1">Text Content 1</option>
  <option label="label 2" value="2">Text Content 2</option>
  <option label="label 3" value="3">Text Content 3</option>
  <option label="label 4" value="4">Text Content 4</option>
</select>
```

If I just set attribute making it selected then it dont work because button for submit appears only when element is selected.

I also tried just to click element to open dropdown and then again click desired option but again it gave me no results.

```
foreach (GeckoHtmlElement geckoHtmlElement in gwBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
{
    if (geckoHtmlElement.GetAttribute("class") == "ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched")
    {
        geckoHtmlElement.Click();
    }
}
```

Actually it finds element but clicking dont do anything.
So maybe there is any fancy js method to select that dropdown?

Comment: possible dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259192/fill-a-select-box-using-geckofx-c-sharp/33270324#33270324

Comment: Its almost same if I just edit html by myself and set selected element. It dont trigger some kind of js to show submit button

Answer (score 0):

From the portion `class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"` it looks like there is [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) at work here - because angular usually uses the prefix `ng-`. Angular can intercept user actions and take control of how your web page controls behave.